# How to store users under E:\Documents and Settings instead of C:\ in XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, user-profiles

I know it is an outdated topic, but still I need a help on this. In XP, how do I store users under `E:\Documents and Settings` instead of `C:\`? I have been trying many methods, but nothing works. The recent one I tried is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList \ProfilesDirectory Reg_Sz Default value = "E:\Documents and Settings"
```

After changing the registry value, it is not storing profiles any more. Can anyone please tell me how to fix it? The XP machine is not connected to any domain, only a workgroup. I really want user folders to be saved under `E:\`.

[image: XP Error Message Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

A quick tutorial :

1. Start > Run > Type `compmgmt.msc` > System Tools > Local Users and
   Groups > Users
2. Right-click the user account for which you want to specify a home folder, and then click Properties.
3. Go to Profile tab and specify a new path using Local Path option
4. Apply > OK

You can also refer to a more detailed tutorial [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/lsm_profile_homedirectory.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: I edited my answer and added a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can easily re-direct some folders within your home.  Navigate to your home folder, right click My Documents -> Properties, and there should be a Location tab, which you can point to wherever.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the **ALL** the registry key values from the `C:\Documents and Settings` to `E:\Documents and Settings`. This we have to do it, after installing the OS. Because for a single user, it contains multiple registry values at a different location. Everything is working just fine now!!! 
Thanks for everyone who helped me!